# Removing trailing bin/java at end of environmental variable in linux

Tags: java, linux, environment-variables, mahout

I am trying to compile mahout, I have temporarily changed the JAVA_HOME variable like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.33.x86_64/
```

and 
I checked that it was changed correctly using this command:

```
printenv |grep JAVA_HOME
```

which returns:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.33.x86_64
```

But when I run mahout **mvn clean install -DskipTests=true** 
I run into this error:

**Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.33.x86_64/bin/java**

I am not sure how this bin/java has shown up. The questions that seem similar to mine with the trailing bin/java don't seem to be quite the same as mine or don't make sense because the answer is just to remove it but I never had it in my path in the first place.

How can I solve this `bin/java` issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this in case others run into the same problem. If this post becomes old make sure you have the correct java file name version in the name!

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.35.x86_64/

I had the wrong name for the java path it should be:

java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.35.x86_64/
**NOT** java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.33.x86_64

35 NOT 33

Answer (score 0):

You should append `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to the environment variable PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: well it looks like the problem was export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.35.x86_64/  it's the difference between 33 and 35. It should be 35. Thanks anyways!